# Mutually recursively defined typeclass methods with defaults

Tags: haskell, generics, typeclass

I would like to define a typeclass that has two methods, where implementing any one is enough (but you can implement both independently if needed). This situation is the same as in `Eq`, where `x == y = not (x /= y)` and `x /= y = not (x == y)`. So far so good, I could do exactly the same:

```
class (FunctorB b) => DistributiveB (b :: (Type -> Type) -> Type) where
  bdistribute :: (Distributive f) => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)
  bdistribute x = bmap (\f -> Compose $ fmap f . bsequence' <$> x) bshape

  bshape :: b ((->) (b Identity))
  bshape = bdistribute' id

bdistribute' :: (DistributiveB b, Distributive f) => f (b Identity) -> b f
bdistribute' = bmap (fmap runIdentity . getCompose) . bdistribute
```

However, I would also like to provide a generic *default* implementation of `bdistribute`, which I can do if `bdistribute` doesn't have a definition:

```
class (FunctorB b) => DistributiveB (b :: (Type -> Type) -> Type) where
  bdistribute :: (Distributive f) => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)

  default bdistribute
    :: forall f g
    .  CanDeriveDistributiveB b f g
    => (Distributive f) => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)
  bdistribute = gbdistributeDefault

  bshape :: b ((->) (b Identity))
  bshape = bdistribute' id
```

However, as soon as I want to do both, it breaks:

```
class (FunctorB b) => DistributiveB (b :: (Type -> Type) -> Type) where
  bdistribute :: (Distributive f) => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)
  bdistribute x = bmap (\f -> Compose $ fmap f . bsequence' <$> x) bshape

  default bdistribute
    :: forall f g
    .  CanDeriveDistributiveB b f g
    => (Distributive f) => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)
  bdistribute = gbdistributeDefault

  bshape :: b ((->) (b Identity))
  bshape = bdistribute' id
```

with the following error message:

> Conflicting definitions for `bdistribute`

Now, I can see how this error makes sense; but also, I think what I'd like is also reasonable and well-defined: if you hand-write your `DistributiveB` instance you can override `bdistribute` and/or `bshape`, but if you just write `instance DistributiveB MyB` then you get `bshape` defined in terms of `bdistribute` and `bdistribute` defined from `gdistributeDefault`.

Comment: What if you add an associated type family with a default instance and let that control how to default the method?

Comment: @dfeuer can you elaborate on that idea?

Comment: Yes, but not tonight. What I'm suggesting will require a bit more boilerplate than you really want, so it doesn't necessarily win over just exposing functions.

Comment: It looks like, if an instance does not have its own implementation, the compiler has to test whether `CanDeriveDistributiveB b f g` holds: if it does, then the implementation is `gbdistributeDefault`, otherwise the implementation is `bmap (\f -> Compose $ fmap f . bsequence' <$> x) bshape`. This kind of test (if this constraint is satisfied then ... else ...) looks impossible to perform with Haskell, as far I can see.

Comment: Are you asking why the `DefaultSignatures` extension doesn't (or couldn't be easily extended) to accept this program, or are you asking how to do this with GHC "as it is" without too much boilerplate?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr The latter, definitely the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compromise is to drop the first default definition: by the time a user is manually implementing `bshape`, it's not too much to ask to add one line to get the other "default" implementation of `bdistribute` from it.

```hs
class FunctorB b => DistributiveB b where
  bdistribute :: Distributive f => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)

  default bdistribute :: CanDeriveDistributiveB b f g => ...
  bdistribute = ...

  bshape :: b ((->) (b Identity))
  bshape = ...

-- Default implementation of bdistribute with an explicitly defined bshape
bdistributeDefault :: DistributiveB b => f (b g) -> b (Compose f g)
bdistributeDefault x = bmap (\f -> Compose $ fmap f . bsequence' <$> x) bshape
```

So the instances look like this:

```hs
-- Generic default
instance DistributiveB MyB

-- Manual bshape
instance DistributiveB MyB where
  distribute = distributeDefault  -- one extra line of boilerplate
  bshape = ...  -- custom definition

-- Manual distribute
instance DistributiveB MyB where
  distribute = ...
  -- bshape has a default implementation
```